# getByRole for text under li > a on test-library

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library, testing-library

I would like to use `getByRole` to write the test and I have html like following. when I use `linkitem` or 'link' as role. I cannt find element

```
// err
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listitem" and name "Click Me"

    Here are the accessible roles:

      --------------------------------------------------
      list:

      Name "":
      <ul
        class="bar-dropdownList"
      />

      --------------------------------------------------
      listitem:

      Name "":
      <li
        class="bar-container"
      />

      Name "":
      <li
        class="bar-actionContainer"
      />

      --------------------------------------------------
// test.tsx
    const name = screen.getByRole('listitem', {name: 'Click Me'});

// from screen.debug()

<ul class="bar-dropdownList">
    <li class="bar-container">
      <div>
        <a class="bar-button">
          <span class="bar-label">Click Me</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a class="bar-button">
          <span class="bar-label">Address</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with how accessible names are determined, but I imagine that `name` isn't matching because the list item has two children with text content...?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that React Testing Library will not recognize an anchor as a `role="link"` if it doesn't have an `href`.  You can [test this using RTL's Testing Playground](https://testing-playground.com/) -- if you try to query by the `link` role you'll get a node returned, but if you remove the `href` it returns nothing.  You'll *also* note that if you remove the `href` and then attempt to navigate through the document by tabbing on the keyboard, the anchor element is now *skipped* and never receives focus.  This is most likely the reason why RTL makes this distinction: browsers treat an anchor without an `href` differently from an accessibility perspective.  RTL tends to be pretty good about the rules it uses to match by accessible roles, so if it were me I'd err on the side of assuming that an anchor without an `href` represents an accessibility antipattern, and reassess how this is being built.